# Static/Instance

Tags: java, static

Встретил в книге данный пример. Никак не могу понять, почему метод third() дает ошибку? В книге написанно, ошибка возникает из-за того, что "не статическому методу присваивается статическая ссылка" Но ведь переменная name не является статической. Или я что-то не правильно понял? Заранее спасибо!

```
public class Static {
 private String name = "Static class";
 public static void first() { }
 public static void second() { }
 public void third() { System.out.println(name); }
 public static void main(String args[]) {
 first();
 second();
 third(); // DOES NOT COMPILE
 } }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что для вызова нестатического метода необходим объект (instance).

Дело не в том, что внутри `third` используется поле `name`, а в том, что этот метод вызывается напрямую из другого статического метода.

```
new Static().third();
```

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя использовать нестатические переменные и методы в статических методах, без создания объекта.